# Estimate probability that all values have been seen

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Assume I gather $n$ realizations of a random variable $X$ taking finitely many values in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose the number of distinct values $m$ is small compared to the sample size $n$.

How do I estimate the probability that the support of $X$ has more than $m$ distinct elements?
For example, assume that the observed distinct values $\{x_1, x_2, \dots x_{m}\}$ have a probability of $p_\mathrm{obs} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}p(x_i) < 1$. This means one of the unobserved values has nonzero probability. Let us further assume no unseen events has $0$ probability, that is for all values $x$ that $X$ takes, one has $p(x) > \delta > 0$ for $\delta$ fairly small (say $10^{-3}$)

The likelihood $\ell=P(E)$ of the event

$$E =\text{"the sample does not cover every value that}\; X\;\text{can take"} $$
is $(1 - p_\mathrm{obs})^{n}$, which should be fairly small. If we set a high threshold $\alpha \approx 0.99$ above which we consider there is sufficient proof for $E$, the inequality $\ell > \alpha$ happens if and only if
$$n > \dfrac{\log\alpha}{\log(1 - p_\mathrm{obs})}$$
However this lower bound isn't useful, as for most values of $1-p_\mathrm{obs}$ it does not go above $1$.

### Question

What would be a good way to estimate whether I have high enough $n$ to decide whether the event $E$ is true ? Here I assume $1-p_\mathrm{obs}$ is fixed and I'd like a lower bound as a function of $p_\mathrm{obs}$.

Comment: Usually a variable is known to be discrete because of its definition. Trying to infer whether a variable is discrete from the number of unique (better: distinct) values is doomed to difficulty. Zip or other post codes, company names, counts of people in settlements are all fundamentally discrete but with many possible distinct values. Height of people in cm is in principle continuous but a dataset might include less than 100 distinct values.  Independently of that, the probabilities here all seem hard to estimate and even to define rigorously.

Comment: This problem is intuitively appealing because as the sample size grows, if the number of distinct values stagnates/stabilizes we should be able to answer the question.

Comment: Then a perfectly good answer to the question would be: there is a sample size above which we have a good chance to detect all the values $X$ can take?

Comment: It is for you to decide what answer is acceptable; that is how CV works.  The idea that larger samples are more likely to include all possible distinct values is certainly plausible but I doubt you'll get more precise results with a very general formulation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated my question to be more specific. Let's assume the variable is indeed finitely supported, but I want to know whether all values have been seen.

Comment: The question is not well posed because any answer depends on assumptions about the probabilities of the unobserved values. Any answer $m$ or larger is plausible because the unobserved values may have arbitrarily small probabilities.

Comment: Right. Let's first ask whether there is at least one unobserved value.

Comment: I don't quite understand: what constraints do you need once the probability of the observed is fixed?

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question whether there is at least one unobserved value, because there *always* could be, provided its probability is small enough.  You simply don't provide enough information to answer any of your questions.  Examples of sufficient information would be (1) specifying a parametric family of distributions or (2) specifying a nonzero lower bound on all the probabilities.

Comment: The second option is perfectly fine to me. I'll edit my question!